# Crawling for sites that use specific JS API

Tags: web-crawler

We're trying to determine what's the best strategy/tool to use to find crawl the web for sites which use a specific JS API/service.

For example, we'd like to determine the number of sites that use Google Analytics.

Of course, we could just check the presence of a `UA-XXX-XX` variable, but then, if we wanted to look for the sites that use Disqus, that would not work... etc. We'd rather run a headless browser and look at pages which make network connections to `www.google-analytics.com`.

What would be the best strategy for this?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do this.

1. Implement a web crawler or snoop browsers or networks
2. Trick an existing crawler into surrendering this information
3. Get it from somebody who has already collected it.

You're asking about #1, but let me address the others first.

Google's search allows things like `link:google-analytics.com` to search for web pages that offer links to `google-analytics.com`, but as [it turns up zero results](https://www.google.com/search?q=link:google-analytics.com), I am guessing `link:` refers to an `<a href="*">` anchor rather than loading a component of a page.  So it doesn't look like Google will help here.

Perhaps searching the code on e.g. [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=google-analytics.com) would give you some information.  This doesn't give you a comprehensive view of the web, but it does present a window.

Ghostery, which makes a [privacy add-on for browsers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/), makes its money by levering its users that opt into sending data to their servers.  They then sell that data to companies so they can see how they violate their own privacy policies (this is an over-simplification).  This means Ghostery [has this information](https://www.ghostery.com/en/apps/google_analytics) and sells it as part of its [Marketing Cloud Management](https://www.ghosteryenterprise.com/marketing-cloud-management/) service.

*Don't reinvent the wheel when you don't have to!*  Ghostery has this data.  So do Alexa, BuiltWith, and Pingdom (as noted in Wikipedia's [Google Analytics Popularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics#Popularity) section).

---

As to doing this yourself, it depends on your resources.  If you run a corporate network, you could probably just sniff the packets using something like [Snort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort_%28software%29), or (if you have more control) a caching transparent web proxy like [Squid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29).  If you have a user base, you could write a browser add-on similar to Ghostery (at least from the data collection side).

Otherwise you would have to implement your own crawler (there are [several to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers)) and then let it loose on the web, though you might have to write signatures for the kinds of things you're looking for as you likely do not want to be executing arbitrary javascript.

I imagine you'd get quite far with any of them.  Scraping one or two levels into each of the [Alexa Top 500](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) websites should be a pretty good start.

Once you've started to collect data (by whatever method you choose), you'll then need to process it so you can delete it before you run out of disk space.  I think a list of pre-defined regular expressions (basically, `grep` calls) to match the items you're seeking is likely sufficient.  Tally and delete.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use python scrapy and add a middleware to scrapy to send all page requests to selenium grid. Then pages will be requested and parsed with selenium and you would be able to use and access the data in python scrapy.

use:

https://github.com/brady-vitrano/dsgrid

http://scrapy.org/

Here is a scrapy selenium middleware that will send all requests with dsgrid and allow you to work with the processed pages in scrapy like normal using xpath. You can also create a middleware that will only do stuff when it sees a specific domain, and other cool stuff. This way you can also use PhantomJS to crawl the pages and interact with them in python scrapy or any other driver.

I wrote this a long time ago and haven't used it for a while, but I remember it was working perfectly for me.

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.conf import settings

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service import Service as PhantomJSService

# from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
# display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
# display.start()

selenium_grid_url = "http://172.17.0.2:4444/wd/hub"

reuseable_driver = None

phantomjs_path = '/usr/bin/phantomjs'


class WebDriverProxy():
    def chrome_driver(self):
        pass

    def firefox_driver(self):
        pass

    def phantomjs_driver(self):
        # monkey patch Service temporarily to include desired args
        class NewService(PhantomJSService):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                service_args = kwargs.get('service_args', list())
                proxy = '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050'
                proxytype = '--proxy-type=socks5'
                if service_args is not None:
                    service_args += [
                        proxy,
                        proxytype,
                    ]
                else:
                    service_args = [
                        proxy,
                        proxytype,
                    ]
                super(NewService, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.Service = NewService
        # init the webdriver
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs_path)
        # undo monkey patch
        webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.Service = PhantomJSService
        return driver


def get_driver(driver_type=None, implicitly_wait=10):
    if reuseable_driver is not None:
        driver = reuseable_driver
    else:
        if driver_type:
            driver = None

            # capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()

            if not driver and 'phantomjs' in driver_type.lower():
                driver = WebDriverProxy().phantomjs_driver()
                # driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
                # capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
            if not driver and 'firefox' in driver_type.lower():
                driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                # capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
            if not driver and 'chrome' in driver_type.lower():
                driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                # capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
            if not driver:
                driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

            # driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=capabilities, command_executor=selenium_grid_url)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

        driver.implicitly_wait(implicitly_wait)

    return driver


def ajax_complete(driver):
    try:
        return 0 == driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
    except WebDriverException:
        pass


def driver_wait(driver, itime, callback):
    #wait for ajax items to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, itime).until(callback,)

    assert "ajax loaded string" in driver.page_source


class SeleniumDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if hasattr(spider, 'use_selenium') and spider.use_selenium:
            #check if spider has driver defined if not just use from settings
            if hasattr(spider, 'selenium_driver'):
                driver_type = getattr(spider, 'selenium_driver', settings.get('SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER'))
            else:
                driver_type = settings.get('SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER')

            driver = get_driver(driver_type=driver_type)

            driver.get(request.url)

            #set that this request was made with selenium driver
            request.meta['is_selenium'] = True

            html = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.innerHTML;')
            if '</pre></body>' in html:
                if 'head><body><pre' in html:
                    if '<head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">' in html[0:78]:
                        html = html.replace('<head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">', '')
                    elif '</head><body><pre>' in html:
                        html = html.split('</head><body><pre>')[1]
                if '</pre></body>' in html[-13:]:
                    html = html.replace('</pre></body>', '')

            url = driver.execute_script('return window.location.href;')

            response = HtmlResponse(
                url=url,
                encoding='utf-8',
                body=html.encode('utf-8'),
                request=request,
            )
            #close browser if we say in spider to close it
            if hasattr(spider, 'selenium_close_driver') and\
                    getattr(spider, 'selenium_close_driver') is True:
                reuseable_driver = None
                driver.close()

            return response
        return None
```

Just like the SeleniumDownloaderMiddleware above, you can create another middleware called GoogleAnalyticsCountMiddleware, it will take the response see that it is for www.google-analytics.com and increment a counter or parse the UA-XXX-XX and increment the count on that in the array or in the database(SQLAlchemy).

You could then go further by implementing more Middlewares in Scrapy and saving data to your database with the DatabaseMiddleware or APIMiddleware that you create to communicate to your API that you have build for accepting these datas.